# Erro Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, migrations, entity-framework-core

Estou com um erro com Entity Framework core quando vou adicionar o Migration, aparece o seguinte erro para mim:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot use table 'Atleta' for entity type 'Pessoa' since it is being used for entity type 'Atleta' and there is no relationship between the primary key {'PessoaId'} and the primary key {'AtletaId'}.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.ValidateSharedTableCompatibility(IReadOnlyList`1 mappedTypes, String tableName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.SqlServerModelValidator.ValidateSharedTableCompatibility(IReadOnlyList`1 mappedTypes, String tableName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.ValidateSharedTableCompatibility(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.SqlServerModelValidator.Validate(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<GetModel>b__0(Object k)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_1(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.get_DatabaseCreator()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.EnsureCreated()
   at acme.one.ride.infra.Config.Context..ctor(DbContextOptions`1 connString) in C:\Users\linne\source\repos\acme.one.ride\acme.one.ride.infra\Config\Context.cs:line 14
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass12_2.<FindContextTypes>b__11()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Cannot use table 'Atleta' for entity type 'Pessoa' since it is being used for entity type 'Atleta' and there is no relationship between the primary key {'PessoaId'} and the primary key {'AtletaId'}.
```

As minhas classes estão assim:
Pessoa:

```
    public class Pessoa : IPessoa
{

    public Pessoa()
    {
        VideosPessoas = new HashSet<VideoPessoa>();
        MedidasAdaptacoesBicicletas = new HashSet<MedidasAdaptacaoBicicleta>();
        Contas = new HashSet<Conta>();
        EnderecosPessoas = new HashSet<EnderecoPessoa>();
        Fotos = new HashSet<Foto>();
        Treinadores = new HashSet<Treinador>();
        Atletas = new HashSet<Atleta>();
        DispositivosPessoas = new HashSet<DispositivoPessoa>();
    }

    private long _pessoaId;
    private string _nome, _sobrenome, _email, _sexo, _celular;
    private DateTime _dataDeNascimento;
    private double _peso;
    private double? _altura;

    public long PessoaId { get => _pessoaId; set => _pessoaId = value; }
    public string Nome { get => _nome; set => _nome = value; }
    public string Sobrenome { get => _sobrenome; set => _sobrenome = value; }
    public string Email
    {
        get => _email;
        set
        {
            _email = value;
        }
    }
    public string Sexo { get => _sexo; set => _sexo = value; }
    public DateTime DataDeNascimento { get => _dataDeNascimento; set => _dataDeNascimento = value; }
    public string Celular { get => _celular; set => _celular = value; }
    public double Peso { get => _peso; set => _peso = value; }
    public double? Altura { get => _altura; set => _altura = value; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<VideoPessoa> VideosPessoas { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<MedidasAdaptacaoBicicleta> MedidasAdaptacoesBicicletas { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Conta> Contas { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<EnderecoPessoa> EnderecosPessoas { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Foto> Fotos { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Treinador> Treinadores { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Atleta> Atletas { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<DispositivoPessoa> DispositivosPessoas { get; set; }


}
```

E atleta esta Assim:

```
public class Atleta
{
    public Atleta()
    {
        TiposAtletasAtletas = new HashSet<TipoAtletaAtleta>();
        TreinadoresAtletas = new HashSet<TreinadorAtleta>();
        AgendasTreinos = new HashSet<AgendaTreino>();
        TreinosAtletas = new HashSet<TreinoAtleta>();
    }
    [Key]
    public long AtletaId { get; set; }
    public virtual long AtletaIdPessoa { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("AtletaIdPessoa")]
    public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TipoAtletaAtleta> TiposAtletasAtletas { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TreinadorAtleta> TreinadoresAtletas { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<AgendaTreino> AgendasTreinos { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<TreinoAtleta> TreinosAtletas { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: tira isso: `[ForeignKey("AtletaIdPessoa")]` e isso:  `public virtual long AtletaIdPessoa { get; set; }` no EF Core, não precisa da propriedade sendo a chave primaria de outro objeto

Comment: Continua o erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde!

Imagino que Pessoa e Atleta estejam no relacionamento 1:1 e o Code First.

Leia este artigo: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Este site possui muitos artigos sobre EF.
Mas uma observação muito importante é que o ideal é que você utilize Code-First Convention, que é nada mais nada menos que padrão de nomenclatura, principalmente para Objetos relacionais, em EF o padrão de nomenclatura faz muita diferença.

Pelo que percebo existem varias coisas a serem feitas no seu código para resolver o problema. E Todas as respostas estão no Code-First Convention.

Vamos lá.

1) Para as chaves primárias de suas classes você deve nomeá-las apenas como Id

Pessoa ->

```
public long Id {get;set;}
```

Atleta ->

```
public long Id {get;set;}
```

- não precisa do data annotation atribute [Key]
- Sugiro que você use Guid para suas chaves

Em atleta a propriedade pessoa que está assim:

```
[Required]
[ForeignKey("AtletaIdPessoa")]
public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
```

Ficaria assim:

```
public long PessoaId { get; set; }
public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
```

Por causa da convenção, o EF irá resolver as chaves para você.

Espero que agora eu possa ter te ajudado melhor, se precisar de mais detalhes só falar.

Comment: Rodrigo, legal a intenção de ajudar, mas seria legal um exemplo do como resolver o problema alem do link, e que sejá um link relacionado a versão do EF.

Comment: Ok, então preciso de confirmar essas entidades realmente estão no relacionamento 1:1 ?

Comment: espero que agora eu tenha respondido a contento, obrigado!

Comment: Eu vou fazer o que você me disse e assim que fizer as modificações Te falo se deu ou não certo, Muito Obrigado pela Ajuda.

Comment: blz, fico no aguardo então.

Comment: Foi  o que você falou mas faltou um ForeingKey("Pessoa") Em cima do Id do Atleta se não não funciona.

Comment: Aproveitando Rodrigo o Entity Framework tem limitação de Foreing Key ?

Comment: O Foreing Key foi um esquecimento meu, vou melhorar a resposta. Não entendi que você quis dizer com limitação.

Comment: Limitação assim, o Entity Framework core não deixa uma classe ter mais de 3 chaves estrangeiras por entidade ou uma classe não pode estar ligada a mais de três entidades

Comment: Nunca tive problema com isso, tenho entidades com mais de 8 relacinamentos